# Comparing $x*f(x)$ with C.D.F., $F(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

If $x$ is a continuous r.v., with pdf as $f(x)$ and cdf as $F(x)$, then say I take $x=A$, and wish to compare the quantities ($A*f(A)$) with $F(A)$. Since
$F(A)=\int_0^Af(x)dx$
doesn't it follow that $F(A)>A*f(A)$?
However, I also have this argument: Consider a discrete distribution where $f(x)$ has value 4 in the range 0.95 to 1.00.  The value of $xf(x)$ in this range will be around 4, but the contribution to $F(x)$ is only 0.05*4 = 0.20.  The value of $F(x)$ meanwhile is 1.00.  So $xf(x) > F(x)$.
Where am I going wrong? Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: CDF is an integral starting from $-\infty$ not from $0$, unless the random variable only takes non-negative values. This is not the main issue, but just pointing out.

Comment: The first part of the question talks about continuous r.v. Then in your argument, it says a "discrete" distribution.

Comment: Now, forget about r.v. etc. for a second. Let's consider $G(A)=\int_0^A g(x) \, dx.$ Then $G(A)$ represents the area under the curve $g$ from $0$ to $A$. Also, $A \times g(A)$ represents the area of the rectangle with height $g(A)$ laid on the axis on the interval $[0,A]$. Without any conditions on $g$, I dont think we can say generally whether $G(A)$ is bigger or smaller than $A \times g(A)$.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer: My bad! I should have mentioned the support is [0,Inf]. I mentioned the discrete one just as an example to show how I am getting confused. After all, the concepts would remain the same, whether the distribution is cont or discrete. Thanks for the last comment too. I sorted out the issue. Thanks for your time.